# TS Conditional type not recognizing conditional param

Tags: typescript

I need, in simplest terms, a function that returns *either* type "Person" or type "PersonWithSurname". This works fine with a conditional type. However I'm struggling to structure the result of this without as ts error.

```ts
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

type PersonWithSurname = Person & { 
  surname : string 
};

type PersonNameConditional<T> = T extends true 
  ? PersonWithSurname 
  : Person; 

function getPerson<T extends boolean>(returnSurname: withSurname
  ): PersonNameConditional<T> {
    if (returnSurname) {
      return { name: "John", surname: "Wic-k" } as PersonNameConditional<withSurname>
    } else {
      return { name: "John" } as PersonNameConditional<withSurname>
    }
}

// All good here ✅
```

The above works fine and even IntelliSense shows me which type comes back based on the param is received, as seen below.

```ts
const result = getPerson(true) // { name: "John", surname: "Wic-k" }: PersonWithSurname
const result = getPerson(false) // { name: "John" }: Person

// All good here ✅
```

However here I'm running into an issue where TS does not recognise `surname` from the response.

```ts
const requestedSurname: boolean = req.query.withSurname

let result = getPerson(requestedSurname)

if ("surname" in result)
  // All good here  ✅
  result.surname = result.surname.replace(/-/g, '')

if (result.surname)
  // ❌ Property "surname" does not exist on type { name : string } | PersonWithSurname
  result.surname = result.surname.replace(/-/g, '')

// the ideal usage
if (requestedSurname) 
  // ❌ Property "surname" does not exist on type { name : string } | PersonWithSurname
  result.surname = result.surname.replace(/-/g, '')

return result;
```

Is it not possible to use the conditional variable?

Comment: you have to narrow the type of `result` - typescript won't flow those changes from another variable

Comment: Is it not possible to do without narrowing? Ideally using the variable defined as the condition for the type?

Comment: What about using type assertion? just like `result = result as PersonWithSurname` when `requestedSurname` is `true`.

Comment: ① Do you mind if I edit your code to be a [mre] without typos / undeclared values / unconventional type parameter names? ② What you're asking for is unfortunately not possible; `requestedSurname` and `result`'s types are just unions, and unions in TS are not automatically "correlated" the way you want.  See [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  (continued...)

Comment: (...see prev comment) TS can't "see" abstract relationships between apparently unrelated variables, and it can't spend the resources to simulate every possible narrowing, nor is there a "handle" to do that yourself (see [ms/TS#25051](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051)). `"surname" in result` is probably the best check you'll be able to use.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, I was hoping I could use the `requestedSurname` and not do `("surname" in result)` check. But doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible.   TypeScript only supports [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) in very specific limited scenarios, and your scenario is not one of them.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#37223](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37223), [microsoft/TypeScript#54041](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54041), and [microsoft/TypeScript#54252](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54252) for examples where people expected this sort of thing to happen, and the answer is "sorry, that's not how TS works".

---

TypeScript does not "distribute" control flow analysis over every [union-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) value it encounters.  What I mean is, when looking at code like

```
declare const requestedSurname: boolean;
let result = getPerson(requestedSurname);
// let result: Person | PersonWithSurname
if (requestedSurname) {
    result.surname
}
```

the compiler *does not* simulate every possible narrowing of `requestedSurname` and say "`requestedSurname` is `true | false` so I'd better split the possible worlds into `true` and `false` and see what happens.  In the `true` world, `result` will be `PersonWithSurname`, and the `result.surname` block will be valid.  In the `false` world, `result` will be `Person` and the `result.surname` block will never be executed.  Either way `result.surname` is valid and results in a `string` whenever it is reachable."

This might seem like a reasonable approach, but only if you can choose *not* to do it most of the time.  Imagine code like:

```
declare const twoHundredBooleans: boolean[]
const twoHundredPeople = twoHundredBooleans.map(getPerson);
if (twoHundredBooleans.every((b): b is true => b)) {
    twoHundredPeople.map(p => p.surname);
}
```

(where you imagine I've actually written out the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) corresponding to 200 `boolean` elements).  The compiler isn't an intelligent human being, so it can't just see "the big picture".  Any analysis that splits into multiple passes per union member would end up requiring 2<sup>200</sup> iterations and would not be completed before the end of human existence.

At one point I had suggested an opt-in mechanism for such analysis, at [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051), but it was declined.  So there's no handle a developer can turn to get some of this behavior.  It's just not how the compiler works.

---

So this isn't what happens.  What does happen is that the compiler just treats the type of `result` and the type of `requestedSurname` as *independent* or *uncorrelated* union types.  And thus if you care about the type of `result`, you will need to inspect `result` directly, because the relationship to `requestedSurname` has not been tracked.

The easiest approach would be

```
if ("surname" in result) { result.surname }
```

which uses [`in`-operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) to (unsoundly but conveniently) discriminate unions by presence or absence of a known property key.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3AQL4EFgCeADiuijYQAdWBgAFgGUArlDKVkAXjSYcyAGT4iJDHIXVa9Ju1Zc+AtSAByFCAGEcAE3HAccADYAeACoA+ZWQfZAgAD0gQJwxkehkIHWIAflUhHDFJWXk7BOQaQWEzGBkQBDA3XEYIMHycXxDwiEjogCMsLA8IOBA-AAooKv1MgxofAgBKPKtbSkdI13dvf20SZGAYZD6B+SG7MeWVkn6wfXxSOxoAIgApLAkQC4AaWn1z5AuxBABaAGsL5DZkHBojUbHZZi4ygtfH4cgCIB4MChCAdDltcHgzpRLjc7n8AUCUsJpg5nPMyIsYSsOBwCAB6WnIACCHg8yEYbScyAk0BQgFByTgEBA4OjIfp6DxgACMgUq1SsPViED29NOwzeOPuTz0WSxbw+Pzxk1SonE0helEFwrAoog4rAACYZVUQT14AilcgVRi1ddbvd-kbhAKnBAEB44P1kEKQCL+gBHOJ0CBOHa61rtTogVgda1imQSp1y42bBO2yAp81K1gqnM2u2B9QAH0JaVNqfiaw28cT5fbe2RqLtADptQZ2JwQ2GIyhoyKwAB3LAACWKTn6TgAQm0Ol0MDR0zuQABtAC6lpj1oXy9X6-QWF4HUCV5XkXXW4zu6H5DgvB6spBYysJ2CqLi+a7Ju+h4YEOEAAG7QNwPQ9M0EzIM0qzRIqygBCh-Y5M+N7JneD4QF+P49Lw2HILwI6VoB44CsBFyjnYfygHW+ZgGMOQqsyrLslgnLcpGyD8iseYSrROooCoElgFJBhDv0D6IBAPS0p8tKME8ADkOncQQwFyQpuw8QygAy5GgUD3tAPBvCxlB-E4WC2qQWDWmEwAiuoPD8Kqdi5EYDAgIw-zIM2ILpGa0k5MZDkyRxknxUpEAqUg6madpyB6QZKqSCgwAhp4yAyBgcCVIZ6wlj2yZ9mZyCWag1n8FAdnMZWTkudEIDufUXnWj5Fj+YoNB0MFoUAhFVhRe2sW2pxJmKLJ81JZWKVpWpGlabp+mcEcJxyawQA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That is unfortunate.